# matlab plot graph

Tags: matlab

i want to plot 1 dimension array (x axis) with each row of another array 2 dimension (y axis),,in one graph??
and in the same graph i want to plot a histogram of another array 1 dimension (y axis) with the first array (x axis) ?

a=[1,10]  x axis
b=[5,10]  y axis
c=[1,10]  y axis histogram

Answer (score 0):

This code might help :

```
a = [1,10]
b = [5,10]
c = [1,10]
plot(a,b)
hold on
plot(a,c)
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by 'another array 2 dimension(y axis)' but I hope the above is what you are looking for :)